# Tilt SKSpritenode with physicsbody on platform

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am trying to tilt my SKSpriteNode to the left when I touch a button, but it seems that because of the gravity the SKAction gets stuck.

My goal is to produce something like this (made with Paint, not Simulator):
[image]

1: The player is on the platform because of the gravity.

2: The player gets tilt to the left when touching.

3: (not in the image) The player reverts to 1.

My code so far:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

    player = (SKSpriteNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"player"];
    tiltLeftButton = (SKSpriteNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"tiltLeftButton"];

    SKAction *tiltLeft = [SKAction rotateByAngle:2 duration:1];
    tiltLeftForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:tiltLeft];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if ([touchedNode.name isEqualToString:@"tiltLeftButton"]) {

    [player runAction:tiltLeftForever withKey:@"tiltLeft"];
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if ([touchedNode.name isEqualToString:@"tiltLeftButton"]) {

    [player removeActionForKey:@"tiltLeft"];
    }
}
```

Any suggestions ?

(I need the physicsworld.)

(I want to implement a tilt right button, too. Code in objective-c please.)

Comment: Apply a tilt force > gravity

Comment: You are rotating by 2 radians per second, which is about 114 degrees over 1 second, so ~2 degrees per frame,  What happens is you tilt 2 degrees, gravity then takes over, and pushes your block down.  Either turn off affected by gravity, or increase your tilting amount

Comment: @Knight0fDragon By increasing the angle it tilts more, but its not fluid at all. I want the user to have some control over it later. Like having one button for left and one for right and then be able to balance the player

Comment: you wouldn't increase the angle, you would decrease the duration, or again turn off affected by gravity when you are turning

Comment: @Knight0fDragon okay I'll try that. No turning off affected by gravity would destroy my games logic.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon works much better, but still not playable. Another idea ?

Comment: You turn off gravity only when rotating, you turn it back on when the turn is completed

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'll try that